# Interior mutability vs data hiding to hold fixed the referant of a mutable borrow

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, borrowing, interior-mutability

If we run [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=%20%20%20%20pub%20struct%20A%3C%27a%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20x%3A%20%26%27a%20mut%20[u8%3B%203]%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20main%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20y%20%3D%20%26mut%20[7u8%3B%203]%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20%2F*mut*%2F%20a%20%3D%20A%20%7B%20x%3A%20%26mut%20[0u8%3B%203]%20%7D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20a.x[0]%20%3D%203%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20a.x%20%3D%20y%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20let%20b%20%3D%20%26%2F*mut*%2F%20a%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20b.x[1]%20%3D%202%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!%28%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20a.x%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%0A&version=stable&backtrace=1) then we correctly get the error "cannot assign to immutable field `a.x`".

If we remove the two `//` comments, and comment out this bad line, then we get the error "cannot assign to data in a `&` reference".  This makes sense because `&mut` does not provide interior mutability.  We can reborrow an `&A` freely, so this must not give mutable access, ala `&&mut` is `&&`.

If we remove both the `//` comments and the `/* */` comments, then the whole thing compiles, permitting the bad line that violates our invariant that `a.x` must never be pointed to anything else.

```
pub struct A<'a> {
    pub x: &'a mut [u8; 3],
}

fn main() {
    let y = &mut [7u8; 3];
    let /*mut*/ a = A { x: &mut [0u8; 3] };
    a.x[0] = 3;
    a.x = y;  //// This must be prevented!
    {
        // let b = &/*mut*/ a;
        // b.x[1] = 2;
    }
    println!("{:?}", a.x);
}
```

How should one maintain this invariant that `x` must not be changed?  We could make the field private while providing public dereferencing methods, except writing constructors for `A` in unacceptable.

We can avoid the obnoxious constructor by making a `A` a private member of a wrapper `struct AA(A)` which itself hosts the public dereferencing methods.  Now `AA` needs a trivial constructor, but it does not need arguments for all fields of `A`, does not impact order of execution, etc.  This becomes painful if we need some traits implemented for both `A` and `AA` though.

Yet, another approach would be to use interior mutability by working with `Cell<A>`, accessing it with [`Cell::replace`](https://github.com/Amanieu/rfcs/blob/movecell/text/0000-movecell.md), and putting it back later.  This sounds highly problematic, but shows that more solutions exist.

Any cleaner approaches?

Comment: The other option is to use a `Cell` inside the array. Did you try that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use a `Cell<A>` you could make the array inside the `A` contain `Cell<u8>`s:

```
use std::cell::Cell;

pub struct A<'a> {
    x: &'a [Cell<u8>; 3],
}

fn main() {
    // let y = &mut [7u8; 3];
    let a = A { x: &[Cell::new(0u8), Cell::new(0u8), Cell::new(0u8)] };
    a.x[0].set(3);
    // a.x = y;
    {
        let b = &a;
        b.x[1].set(2);
    }
    println!("{:?}", a.x);
}
```

This will still behave how you want, with the same performance, but now the `a` variable is immutable, so you can't change `a.x`. You also don't need to make the array reference mutable either.

The slight downside with your example is that you can't use the array repetition syntax, since `Cell<T>` does not implement `Copy`. This seems like an omission, but there is some explanation as to why that is [here](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/why-is-cell-not-copy/2208/5).

Comment: Interesting.  :)  I suppose one could take `x: Cell<[u8; 3]>` too to give array syntax, but that risks moving more data.  In fact, I've a bunch of these `x` that chop up a slice from elsewhere, so I'd need `transmute` to use `Cell`, but this is nice to know about.  I could probably do the `x: Cell<[u8; 3]>` version if there was a `split_at_mut` for `Cell<&mut [T]>` or something.  Thanks!

Comment: You _could_ do `let a = A { x: &unsafe { mem::transmute([0u8; 3]) }};` - but it isn't exactly pretty either :)

Comment: I do think a crate that safely handles transmuting between `&mut [T]` and `&mut [Cell<T>]` and between `&mut [T; n]` and `&mut [Cell<T>; n]` sounds useful. :)

Comment: Yes. But it's not so easy because Rust doesn't currently allow you to be generic over the length of an array. You'd have to use a macro to implement it for every size up to some supported maximum.

Comment: It exists for slices in https://github.com/huonw/alias via https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1789

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to define

```
pub struct A<'a> { pub x: HideMut<'a,[u8; 3]> }
```

where

```
use std::ops::{Deref,DerefMut};

struct HideMut<'a,T>(&'a mut T) where T: ?Sized + 'a;

impl<'a,T> HideMut<'a,T> where T: ?Sized {
    pub fn new(m: &'a mut T) -> HideMut<'a,T> { HideMut(m) }
}

impl<'a,T> Deref for HideMut<'a,T> where T: ?Sized {
    type Target = T;
    fn deref(&self) -> &T { self.0 }
}

impl<'a,T> DerefMut for HideMut<'a,T> where T: ?Sized {
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut T { self.0 }
}
```

As written, this does not prevent the problem per se, but it requires you call the `HideMut::new()` constructor to violate it.

Now if we define `HideMut` in the same module as `A`, and maybe do not even export it, then we actually do achieve the desired hiding without any interior mutability.

This second form fails my original requirements because now you cannot use the constructor `A { }`, but depending upon your reasons for not wanting to write a constructor for `A` it may work out.

In either form, this avoids borrowing the whole of `A` as a method would do.